# Antlr 4 curly brace usage

Tags: antlr4

I inherited a scripting language that I'm trying to port over to antlr4. Part of the scripting language uses curly braces to identify variables.

set {myVariable} = "5";

I'm using the java grammar a bit as a guideline where variableExpression is new but Identifier and expression are just copies from java. I have:
variableExpression
    :   '{' Identifier '}'
    ;

parExpression
    :   '(' expression ')'
    ;

but I get an error that { is missing when I have 
set {foo} = "5";

If i change the curly brace to (), it works. ! works. $ does not. Are there special characters that we need to escaped in a certain way to make this work? No, i can't change the use of curly braces (legacy code issues).

I'm currently digging through the doc and web for guidance but if someone already knows the answer, please let me know.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such restriction on using these characters `{}()!$`. As an example let's look at a simple grammar:

```antlr
WS : [ \r\n\t] -> skip;
NAME : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
STRING : '\"' .*? '\"';

script
    : varDeclaration+ EOF;

varDeclaration
    : 'set' variable '=' STRING;

variable
    : '(' NAME ')'
    | '{' NAME '}'
    | '!' NAME '!'
    | '$' NAME '$'
    ;
```

This grammar allows to match code below:

```
set {var1} = "value1"
set (var2) = "value2"
set !var3! = "value3"
set $var4$ = "value4"
```

The result AST looks like this:

[image]